# using bash_completion with cli tool

Tags: bash, completion

I have a custom cli tool that i want to setup with bash_completion but want [tab][tab] to perform an enter action on cmdline.

my bash_completion file for wonder is:

```
_wonder()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "audit nodes tools create debug delete update" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _wonder wonder
```

currently:

```
$ wonder [tab] [tab]
```

returns:

```
ip-10-99-18-249:loco_dsl jasonparmar$ wonder
audit   create  debug   delete  nodes   tools   update
```

What I want is when i use the tools option from wonder:

```
$ wonder tools [tab] [tab]
```

I want the [tab][tab] to force an **enter** on the cmdline

How can i edit my bash_completion file for wonder to achieve this.

Is this even possible with bash_completion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using external tools to simulate keyboard input (such as `xdotool`), try adding this as the first line of your completion function:

```
(( COMP_CWORD > 1 )) && xdotool key Return
```

---

As noted by [@RandomUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10136057/random-user), completion executing a command is unexpected behavior. See, for instance: `echo oops; wonder audit <tab><tab>` and imagine `rm -rf *` instead of `echo`. Consider simply stopping the completion to indicate `wonder` accepts only one argument:

```
(( COMP_CWORD > 1 )) && return
```